# Can Selenium webdriver make a random time beween send keys (to simulate human behaviour when typing)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver to complete a form but would like to simulate human behaviour when typing and not auto filling with my values.

For example:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("Address").send_keys("Anthony Street 35th")
```

I would want to simulate human behavior when typing Anthony Street, with random time pauses between each key stroke.

Can this be done ?

Comment: try sending multiple parts of the string sleeping randomly in between

Comment: I think the better question is why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just send one letter at a time through a loop.

```
address = 'Anthony Street 35'
address_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("Address")
for letter in address:
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))  # sleep between 1 and 3 seconds
    address_elem.send_keys(letter)
```

Comment: I would sleep for fractions of a second 3 seconds * a very long string == very long time